# Change mysql port in laravel 4

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-4

I need to change mysql port for profile my queries in laravel 4.2 and use this config in database.php (config>local>database.php):

```
'mysql' => array(
        'driver'    => 'mysql',
        'host'      => 'localhost',
        'port'      => '4040',
        'database'  => 'database_dev',
        'username'  => '****',
        'password'  => '****',
        'charset'   => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix'    => 'rhn_',
    ),
```

but not work.
How change default mysql port in laravel?

Answer (score 0):

Edit the .env file in laravel and also edit laravel>config>database.php

Comment: This config not work. my env is local and this change in this path: config>local>database.php but not work.

Answer (score 0):

This config worked correctly:

```
'mysql' => array(
    'driver'    => 'mysql',
    'host'      => '127.0.0.1', //instead of localhost
    'port'      => '4040',
    'database'  => 'database_dev',
    'username'  => '****',
    'password'  => '****',
    'charset'   => 'utf8',
    'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
    'prefix'    => 'rhn_',
),
```